# Crossrider Extensions are not getting installed in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, crossrider

I have tried to install demo extension and one test extension created by me in my machine. In chrome and firefox it got installed but in IE click on install doesn't make any change. 
I am using windows 64 bit machine and ie11 browser

Comment: Please can you provide the URL you are using for downloading and installing the extension and I will be happy to take a look. [**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]